# NullPointerException in Spark RDD map when submitted as a spark job

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing, bigdata

We're trying to submit a spark job (spark 2.0, hadoop 2.7.2) but for some reason we're receiving a rather cryptic NPE in EMR. Everything runs just fine as a scala program so we're not really sure what's causing the issue. Here's the stack trace:

> 18:02:55,271 ERROR Utils:91 - Aborting task
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:253)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1325)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

As far as we can tell this is occurring in the following method:

```
def process(dataFrame: DataFrame, S3bucket: String) = {
  dataFrame.map(row =>
      "text|label"
  ).coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).text(S3bucket)
}
```

We've narrowed it down to the map function as this works when submitted as a spark job:

```
def process(dataFrame: DataFrame, S3bucket: String) = {
  dataFrame.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).text(S3bucket)
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue? Also, how can we resolve it? We're pretty stumped.

Comment: Did you try without `coalesce()`?

Comment: @gsamaras No! But it appears to work without coalesce. What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you get a `NullPointerException` thrown by the worker when it tries to access a `SparkContext` object that's only present on the driver and not the workers.

[coalesce()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=coalesce#pyspark.RDD.coalesce) repartitions your data. When you request one partition only, it will try to squeeze *all* the data in one partition<sup>*</sup>. That may put much pressure on the memory footpring of your application.

In general, it is a good idea not to shrink your partitions in only 1.

For more, read this: [Spark NullPointerException with saveAsTextFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923262/spark-nullpointerexception-with-saveastextfile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type).

---

- In case you are not sure what a partition is, I explained it to myself in [memoryOverhead issue in Spark](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/memoryoverhead-issue-in-spark/).

Comment: The reason why we were using coalesce(1) was to write all of the data into a single file instead of many files. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: @cscan no. Maybe increasing your memory settings can allow your application to work with 1 partition, but I the error you posted doesn't indicate something like that. Is there a reason why you want them to be in 1 file?

Comment: This error occurred when we were testing with only five records - I don't think it was related to memory use.

Comment: Me too @cscan! I also updated my answer. BTW, if you **really want to have only one file**, then my tip would be to run the job, let the file be split into parts and afterwards, merge the parts to a single file. But in general, having a single file means not having a lot of data, so maybe Spark may not be needed after all..