# How to save data in pyspark in 1 file in Amazon EMR

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I use next code for save data to local disk

```
receiptR.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('file:/mnt/dump/gp')
```

But I had next directory structure

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-16-209 ~]$ cd /mnt/dump
[hadoop@ip-172-31-16-209 dump]$ ls -R
.:
gp
./gp:
_temporary
./gp/_temporary:
0

./gp/_temporary/0:
task_201610061116_0000_m_000000  _temporary

./gp/_temporary/0/task_201610061116_0000_m_000000:

part-00000
```

How I can save data in next structure?

```
/mnt/dump/gp/
part-00000
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are separated out one per partition. So if you were to view your data on its own, you'd see this.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4) # as "4" partitions
rdd.collect()
--> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and if you view it with partitions visible:

```
rdd.glom().collect() 
--> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

So when you save it, it will save the files broken into 4 pieces.

As others have suggested in similar questions, i.e. [how to make saveAsTextFile NOT split output into multiple file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371259/how-to-make-saveastextfile-not-split-output-into-multiple-file) , you can `coalesce` the dataset down to 1 single partition and then save:

```
coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile("s3://myBucket/path/to/file.txt")
```

However, **warning**: the reason why Spark deals with data across multiple partitions in the first place is because for very large datasets, each node can deal with smaller data. When you `coalesce` down to 1 partition, you're forcing the entirety of the dataset into a single node. if you dont have the memory available for that, you'll get into trouble. Source: [NullPointerException in Spark RDD map when submitted as a spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986776/nullpointerexception-in-spark-rdd-map-when-submitted-as-a-spark-job/38986964#38986964)