# Writing Spark RDD as text file to S3 bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm attempting to save a Spark RDD as a gzipped text file (or several text files) to an S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is mounted to dbfs. I'm trying to save the file using the following:

```
rddDataset.saveAsTextFile("/mnt/mymount/myfolder/")
```

But when trying this, I keep getting the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 32 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 32.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 279, ip-10-81-194-225.ec2.internal): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, I do see a few files written to the S3 bucket. I've also tried using `rddDataset.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/mnt/mymount/myfolder/")`, as advised [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6769/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-rdd-data-to-s3-bucket.html), but this ended in the same error.

This appears to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923262/spark-nullpointerexception-with-saveastextfile), so maybe the errors are due to null values in my RDD? But when I try `val newRDD = rddDataset.map(line => line).filter(x => x!= null).filter(x => x!=" ").filter(x => x!="")` and try to save this RDD, I get the same error.

Additionally, `rddDataset.count()` throws a similar error. I'm creating rddDataset from a dataframe, which displays all its rows just fine. However, I can reproduce the `java.lang.NullPointerException` if I convert my original dataframe to an RDD:

```
val testRDD = df.rdd
testRDD.count()

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 32 in stage 85.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 32.3 in stage 85.0 (TID 1668, ip-10-81-194-241.ec2.internal): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've provided one of the stack traces below:

```
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1927)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1209)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1154)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1060)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:952)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:951)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1457)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1436)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1436)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1436)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Also, when I open up the information tab for the stage after running `rddDataset.repartition(200).saveAsTextFile(/mnt/mymount/myfolder)`I can find the error details:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at linef9b86491b9da46b9858e22af0cc8257227.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:48)
at linef9b86491b9da46b9858e22af0cc8257227.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.evalExpr35$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:235)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace for the NPE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't properly handling null values in one of my UDFs while pre-processing the data. Concretely, I had to change one of my UDFs from

```
val converter = (arg: String) => {
  arg.split("").mkString("_").replace(":","_") 
}
```

to

```
val converter = (arg: String) => {
  if (arg == null || arg== "") "" else arg.split("").mkString("_").replace(":","_") 
}
```

Everything seemed to work after that.